# Получить массив дат из строки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно, максимально простым способом, получить массив дат из строки? Например из `15.02.2016-17.02.2016` сделать `['15.02.2016','16.02.2016','17.02.2016']`

Comment: формат дат определен?

Comment: да, именно в таком виде d.m.Y в терминологии php )

Comment: тогда: сплит по `-`, перевод строк в даты и обычный цикл

Comment: сложность в том что не совсем понятно, как инкриментить даты, особенно если период с середины месяца и до середины следующего месяца

Comment: в массиве только _дни_ должны быть?

Comment: да, формат выхода я написал в вопросе

Comment: А где ваша попытка решения, автор?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime

Comment: Обратите внимание, `date = new Date(2014, 11, 35);` отлично дает 4 января 15 года (месяцы нумеруются с 0, 11-декабрь). т.е. вы можете просто формировать в цикле даты увеличивая номер дня за пределы меесяца и объект будет содержать правильную дату

Comment: Как уже писали выше, `split` по `-`, а потом какой либо цикл с проверкой достижения конечной даты. А в цикле просто прибавление дней  `result.setDate(current_step_date + 1);`

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function fn(str) {
  str = str.split(/-|\./);
  var arr = [],
    from = new Date(str[2], str[1] - 1, str[0]),
    to = new Date(str[5], str[4] - 1, str[3]);
  for (; from <= to;) {
    arr.push((from.getDate() + "." + (from.getMonth() + 1) + "." + from.getFullYear()).replace(/(^|\.)(?=\d\.)/g, "$10"));
    from.setDate(from.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return arr;
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(fn('15.02.2016-17.02.2016')));
```